# how to adjust size and location of subview according to superview?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have a user resizable view created programmatically using the files downloaded from git [Resize](https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView) I have added a label over this view and I need the label to be at the center of the resizable view always . How can i adjust size and location of the label according to the resizable view?

[image: i have added a sample image down here]

Comment: you can resize and adjust position of the label in a method in which you are resizing your view.

Comment: you can add label to view of you want....and don't give (x,y,height,width)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for autolayout. Should be easily solved using

```
-(NSArray *)centerInView:(UIView*)superview;
```

or

```
-(NSLayoutConstraint *)centerInContainerOnAxis:(NSLayoutAttribute)axis;
```

in the excellent autolayout category found here:

https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout

Examples:

```
[self.imageLabel centerInView:self.imageView];
[self.imageLabel centerInContainerOnAxis:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY];
```